# Get binding location in Word add-n

Tags: office-js, word-addins

Is there a way to get binding location within the document, like maybe a character number at which it appears? Or at least get an order in which bindings appear in the document. getAllAsync gets an array of bindings in order they were added (although not guaranteed). What I need is to know if one appears before the other.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean Word or Excel (sounds like Word?).  But in the new (Office 2016) Excel APIs, you can get a binding object and ask it for its range... from which you can do all sorts of things like use that range, query its address, etc.

```js
Excel.run(function(ctx) {
    var binding = ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem("MyBinding");
    var range = binding.getRange();
    range.load("address");
    return ctx.sync()
        .then(function () {
            console.log(range.address);
        })
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error " + error);
});
```

Hope this helps,

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: thanks for the reply. My add-in is in Word. I would think Excel is a bit different and the "address" is a cell rather than a character number or cursor position. Is there anything like this I can do in Word?